# Using threads in Java, iteratively

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

I was wondering if anyone can help me out with a problem.

What I want to accomplish (using Java):

In first iteration, I want to "doStuff" 10 times (concurrently).

In the second iteration, I want to "doStuff" 20 times (in a concurrent manner) AFTER the first iteration is complete.

etc... (I'd like to be able to loop because I plan to do this over 100 times)

The problem with my code is that it's doing stuff 30 times at once. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Parts of code were removed for simplification so let me know if there are any mistakes.

```
public static void doStuff(){

 [Code]

}

public static void threadThis (int y){

for (int i = 0; i<y; i++) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            doStuff();
        }
    };
    t1.start();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] agrs) throws InterruptedException {


    for (int p = 0; p<21; p = p + 10){
        threadThis(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the second iteration of 20 "doStuff"s to run after the first, you need to implement a hold on the second iteration of threads. Right now there's nothing doing that, so all 30 threads are running and executing when called.

Comment: Have a look at the [fork-join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) tutorial.

Comment: Make your own class that extends the Thread class and as soon as the "doStuff()" function finishes set a boolean finished = true. You can check in a loop for all current running threads and if there finish attribute is all true, you can create 10 more threads doing other stuff.

Comment: Will using `public static synchronized threadThis` not work?

Comment: @Roberto Unfortunately this does not work. Same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change threadThis() to join() all of the threads after it starts them.

```
public static void threadThis (int y){
    List<Thread> threads = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(y);
    for (int i = 0; i<y; i++) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(){...};
        t1.start();
        threads.add(t1);
    }
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good task for **CountDownLatch** class from **java.util.concurrent** package.

Naturally you task split off on **two** big tasks which should be queued, it is exactly CountDownLatch **responsibility**.

Look for [CountDownLatch API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) documentation, there is a good code sample, could be easely adopted to your needs

Comment: Also OP can consider using `CyclicBarrier`.

Answer (score 0):

As the others are saying the concept of `CountDownLatch` will be very useful here. `CountDownLatch` is actually using `wai`t and `notify` underneath. So this is how you can put `wait` and `notif`y to work and implement a similar functionality yourself.

**Main**

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Manager mgr = new Manager("manager");
        mgr.start();

    }
}
```

**Manager**

```
    public class Manager extends Thread
    {
        public int threadCount=0;

        private final Object lock = new Object();

        public Manager(String name){
            super(name);
        }


        public void pauseAndWaitForAll()
        {
            synchronized (this.lock) {
                    try {
                        while(this.threadCount>0)
                        {
                            this.lock.wait();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
             }
        }
        public void countDown()
        {
            synchronized (this.lock) {
                this.threadCount--;

// if the if block becomes uncommented notify will only be called
// by last running thread of group, thus will only be called by last running thread of 
// group. If the if block is left commented out then every thread that is done with its 
// work will call notify and thus wait will be called again due to the 
// while(thread.count>0) loop not terminating


                            //if (this.threadCount <= 0) 
                //{
                    this.lock.notify();
                //}
             }
        }

        public void run () 
        {
            for (int p = 10; p<1001; p = p + 10)
            {
                this.threadCount=p;

                for (int i = 0; i<p; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(" new thread...: "+i+" ");

                    new DoWork(this,"thread: num:"+i+"--group:"+p).start();
                }

                pauseAndWaitForAll();

                // uncomment the following for debugging 
    //          System.out.println(" ------------------next group-----------------------");
    //          try {
    //              Thread.sleep( 3000 ); 
    //          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //              System.out.println(" pause error ");
    //          }
            }
        }
    }
```

**DoWork**

```
public class DoWork extends Thread
{
    private Manager managerThread;

    public DoWork(Manager managerThread,String name){
        super(name);

        this.managerThread=managerThread;
    }


    public void run () 
    {
        try {
//          System.out.print(this.getName()+" going to sleep ...: ");
            int randSleep= 1000*(0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5 - 0) + 1)));
            Thread.sleep(randSleep); 
            System.out.println(this.getName()+" woke up ... ");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(" worker thread: job simulation error:"+e);
        }

        managerThread.countDown();
    }
}
```